# Understanding declval optimized implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, template-instantiation, declval

Looking at libstdc++ source code, I found the following `declval` implementation:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up = _Tp&&>
_Up __declval(int);  // (1)

template<typename _Tp>
_Tp __declval(long); // (2)

template<typename _Tp>
auto declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0));
```

This implementation [was proposed](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27798) by Eric Niebler as a compile time optimization: he explains that overload resolution is faster than template instantiation.

However, I can't understand how it works. Specifically:

1. In (1), why is using `_Up` better than just returning `_Tp&&` ?
2. It seems that the overload (2) is never used. Why is it needed?

How all this prevents template instantiations, as opposed to the most naive implementation:

```
template<typename T>
T&& declval() noexcept;
```

Comment: 1. http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/type_traits?view=diff&r1=269990&r2=269991&pathrev=269991

Comment: @Language Lawyer great, so libc++ implementation doesn't use that 2nd parameter. Still interesting what was the motivation behind it.

Comment: I suspect the answer would be the same as the answer to why the trailing return type was used: [It's just stylistic](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27798#c3). But it is better to ask Eric to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The naive implementation is not fully correct. According to the Standard, `declval` is defined as ([declval]):

> `template <class T> add_rvalue_reference_t<T> declval() noexcept;`

and for `add_rvalue_reference<T>` the Standard reads ([meta.trans.ref]):

> If `T` names a referenceable type then the member typedef `type` names
>   `T&&`; otherwise, `type` names `T`.

An example of a non-referenceable type is `void`. The second overload will be used in that case thanks to SFINAE.

As to the first question, I don't see any special reason. `_Tp&&` should work just fine.